# Picard group of a K3 surface generated by a curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, k3-surfaces, algebraic-curves

In Lazarsfeld's article "Brill Noether Petri without degenerations" he mentions the fact that for any integer $g \geq 2$, one may find a K3 surface $X$ and a curve $C$ of genus $g$ on $X$ such that the Picard group of $X$ is generated by $[C]$. How does one prove that ?

Comment: @Youloush: What precisely are you asking?  Ottem's answer proves that such surfaces exist.  However, if you want to write one down in an explicit way, say over a field like $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ and for $g$ moderately large, that is quite difficult.  For fields like $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, I recommend you look at the work of van Luijk.  For large $g$, the results of Gritsenko, Hulek and Sankaran show that one cannot "algebraically parameterize" general K3 surfaces of large genus.

Answer (score 5):

This is equivalent to saying that there exists a K3 surface with an ample generator (a polarization) $L$, with $L^2=2g-2$ and $|L|$ has a smooth member. There are various geometric ways to construct such surfaces, e.g., by using double covers or quartic surfaces in $\mathbb P^3$ containing special curves. You will find this in VIII.15 in Beauville's book 'Complex Algebraic Surfaces". Given this, one can show the existence of a K3 where $L$ is a generator of the Picard group, using the fact that a generic K3 surface has Picard number 1.