# K3 surface as an anticanonical section

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $S$ be a projective K3 surface. Then is there always a smooth projective 3-fold $V$ that has $S$ as its anticanonical section?

Comment: One comes close with the following example: Consider $V = S \times \mathbb{P}^1$. Here each anticanonical divisor is isomorphic to either two copies of $S$ or $S$ doubled.

Comment: It seems that it is not a easy question. Let me try to simplify the question. How about the case that $S$ has Picard number one?

Comment: If $S \subset V$ is not ample, Lefschetz Hyperplane Theorem in general fails and so, at least in principle, we have no control on the Picard number of $V$, even if the Picard number of $S$ is $1$. This makes the question quite tricky.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is **no** if one makes the additional assumption that  $S \in |-K_V|$ is *ample*, i.e. that $V$ is a smooth *Fano threefold*,  as shown by the following example.

If $V$ is a Fano 3-fold containing $S$ as an ample divisor, by the  Lefschetz Hyperplane Theorem the restriction map $$r \colon \textrm{Pic}\,V \longrightarrow \textrm{Pic} \, S$$ is injective (with torsion free cokernel).

Now, it is well-known that for all $g \geq 2$ there exists a polarized $K3$ surface $(S, \, L)$ of genus $g$ such that $\textrm{Pic} \, S$ is generated by $L$, see for instance

[Picard group of a K3 surface generated by a curve](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/124880/picard-group-of-a-k3-surface-generated-by-a-curve)

Therefore the injectivity of $r$ implies $\rho(V)=1$, or equivalently $b_2(V)=1$.

On the other hand, we know by the work of Iskovskih that smooth Fano threefolds with $b_2=1$ form a bounded family (they belong to exactly $17$ isomorphism classes).

Therefore, if $g$ is large enough (it sufficies to take $g \geq 13$) we necessarily have $b_2(V) \geq 2$, a contradiction.

**Remark 1.** A. Beauville proved in [this paper](http://math1.unice.fr/~beauvill/pubs/Fano.pdf) that a general $K3$ surface with given Picard lattice $R$ and polarization
class $L \in R$ is an anticanonical divisor in a smooth Fano threefold if and only if
there exists an isomorphism of polarized lattices $(R, \, L) = (\textrm{Pic}(V), \, K^{−1}_V)$ for some smooth Fano threefold $V$.

**Remark 2.** As observed in the comments below by D. Litt, J. C. Ottem and Mark, it is actually possible that a $K3$ surface $S$ appears as a *non-ample* anticanonical divisor in a smooth 3-fold, so the question in its general form is still unanswered.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something easy--why does the threefold have to be Fano?  Obviously the anticanonical is effective by hypothesis, but why ample?  (That said +1, this is a very nice answer.)

Comment: By adjunction formula $$(K_V+S)|_S = K_S = \mathcal{O}_S,$$ hence $K_V=-$hyperplane class.

Comment: I must still be missing something.  First of all, to conclude an equality on restriction to S implies anything on V, you need amplitude of S to use Lefschetz.  But that's what we're trying to prove.  Second of all, you only show K_V=-S|_S, again, why is S|_S ample at all?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I misread the question, and I have only proved that $S$ cannot be a *hyperplane* section of a threefold (in this case the threefold is clearly Fano).

Comment: No worries, still a very nice answer!

Comment: Is there any example of a smooth K3 surface $S$ appearing as a non-ample anticanonical divisor in a smooth $3$-fold?

Comment: I thought about it for a while and couldn't come up with one!

Comment: I added this question at the end of my answer.

Comment: Can't you just take a 3-fold where $-K_X$ has a smooth section (e.g., is bpf) but not ample and let $S\in |-K_X|$? For example, blow-up $P^3$ along the 16 nodes of a Kummer surface.

Comment: Let $S \subset \mathbb P^3$ be a smooth quartic and let $X \to \mathbb P^3$ be the blow up a bunch of disjoint curves in $S$ (we can find as many as we want, eg if $S$ is elliptic).  The strict transform of $S$ on $X$ is anticanonical, but won't be ample if you blow up enough curves.